# Finding index of Korean Alphabet (any Unicode char) in Korean Word (any Unicode Word) in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2008-r2, cjk

I have a requirement to search for people by name. Here peoples' names can be in English, Korean, or Chinese languages. For this I used `Like` condition to search on the basis of `Name` as below:

```
select * from [MyTable] where Name like N'%t%'
```

The above statement is giving all the users which contains letter `t`. But this is not working with Korean or Chinese languages. Like if I search with Korean letter **`ㅈ`** then it is supposed to give all the names which contains this letter like `**정수연, 재훈아이팟, 정원혁 테스트 7**`. I have tried the following ways but it's giving zero results

```
select * from [MyTable] where Name like N'%ㅈ%' - No Results
select PATINDEX(N'%ㅈ%',N'정수연(Mohan)') - giving value as ZERO
select Charindex(N'ㅈ',N'정수연') - giving value as ZERO
```

Is there any way to find the letters of the alphabets of other languages in SQL server?

I know how to find alphabet existence in other language in C# words by using encoding techniques but not in SQL server. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT for C# code

```
public static string DecomposeSyllabels(string unicodeString) {
      try {
        //Consonant consonant only used
        string[] JLT = { "ㄱ", "ㄲ", "ㄴ", "ㄷ", "ㄸ", "ㄹ", "ㅁ", "ㅂ", "ㅃ", "ㅅ", "ㅆ", "ㅇ", "ㅈ", "ㅉ", "ㅊ", "ㅋ", "ㅌ", "ㅍ", "ㅎ" };

        // Only used a collection of neutral
        string[] JVT = { "ㅏ", "ㅐ", "ㅑ", "ㅒ", "ㅓ", "ㅔ", "ㅕ", "ㅖ", "ㅗ", "ㅘ", "ㅙ", "ㅚ", "ㅛ", "ㅜ", "ㅝ", "ㅞ", "ㅟ", "ㅠ", "ㅡ", "ㅢ", "ㅣ" };

        // Initial and coda consonants used in
        string[] JTT = { "", "ㄱ", "ㄲ", "ㄳ", "ㄴ", "ㄵ", "ㄶ", "ㄷ", "ㄹ", "ㄺ", "ㄻ", "ㄼ", "ㄽ", "ㄾ", "ㄿ", "ㅀ", "ㅁ", "ㅂ", "ㅄ", "ㅅ", "ㅆ", "ㅇ", "ㅈ", "ㅊ", "ㅋ", "ㅌ", "ㅍ", "ㅎ" };

        double SBase = 0xAC00;
        long SCount = 11172;
        int TCount = 28;
        int NCount = 588;
        string syllables = string.Empty;

        foreach (char c in unicodeString) {
          double SIndex = (int)c - SBase;
          if (0 > SIndex || SIndex >= SCount) {
            syllables = syllables + c;
            continue;
          }

          int LIndex = (int)Math.Floor(SIndex / NCount);
          int VIndex = (int)(Math.Floor((SIndex % NCount) / TCount));
          int TIndex = (int)(SIndex % TCount);
          syllables = syllables + (JLT[LIndex] + JVT[VIndex] + JTT[TIndex]);
        }

        return syllables;
      }
      catch {
        return unicodeString;
      }
    }
```

Comment: The issue is that PATINDEX and CHARINDEX search for characters. Whilst `ㅈ` may be considered to be part of `정`; at the Unicode level `U+3148` isn't "part" of `U+C815` - they're separate characters.

Comment: This problem is related to Unicode normalization. On most platforms except Macintosh, Korean is encoded by syllabic blocks. Mac encodes by letter and the renderer arranges them into syllabic blocks. With a programming language you'll be able to find some code to do `NFC` and `NFD` normalization, but with SQL I have no idea if such functionality exists. It may be worth adding special columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to decompose the Korean syllables and store these into a separate column in your SQL db (like ㅈㅓㅇㅅㅜㅇㅕㄴ for 정수연). I'd suggest you write a small custom app that parses your db, decomposes all Korean syllables, and saves the results into a separate column.

### EDIT

Here's some Python code that will decompose Hangul syllables:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import codecs, sys, os, math

JLT="ㄱ,ㄲ,ㄴ,ㄷ,ㄸ,ㄹ,ㅁ,ㅂ,ㅃ,ㅅ,ㅆ,ㅇ,ㅈ,ㅉ,ㅊ,ㅋ,ㅌ,ㅍ,ㅎ".split(",")
JTT=",ㄱ,ㄲ,ㄱㅅ,ㄴ,ㄴㅈ,ㄴㅎ,ㄷ,ㄹ,ㄹㄱ,ㄹㅁ,ㄹㅂ,ㄹㅅ,ㄹㅌ,ㄹㅍ,ㄹㅎ,ㅁ,ㅂ,ㅂㅅ,ㅅ,ㅆ,ㅇ,ㅈ,ㅊ,ㅋ,ㅌ,ㅍ,ㅎ".split(",")
JVT="ㅏ,ㅐ,ㅑ,ㅒ,ㅓ,ㅔ,ㅕ,ㅖ,ㅗ,ㅘ,ㅙ,ㅚ,ㅛ,ㅜ,ㅝ,ㅞ,ㅟ,ㅠ,ㅡ,ㅢ,ㅣ".split(",")
SBase=0xAC00
SCount=11172
TCount=28
NCount=588

def HangulName(a):
 b=a.decode('utf8')
 sound=''
 for i in b:
  cp=ord(i)
  SIndex = cp - SBase
  if (0 > SIndex or SIndex >= SCount):
    # "Not a Hangul Syllable"
    pass
  LIndex = int(math.floor(SIndex / NCount))
  VIndex = int(math.floor((SIndex % NCount) / TCount))
  TIndex = int(SIndex % TCount)
  sound=sound+(JLT[LIndex] + JVT[VIndex] + JTT[TIndex]).lower()
 return sound

print HangulName("정수연")
```

> dda$ python test.py
> ㅈㅓㅇㅅㅜㅇㅕㄴ

Comment: I have the code in C# to decompose the Korean syllables from a Korean text. By using this code i created SQLCLR function to use in DB but it's taking too much time to decompose. Is there any way to do the decompose in SQL?

Comment: The decomposition SHOULD NOT take long. In fact it's even fast in Javascript. So you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for sharing code. This really helped allot to create C# function. I am adding C# code also to your answer and accepting your answer.