# Find all the Korean characters in a word in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, cjk

I'm trying to get a list of every character of a Korean syllable of input, such as:

```
example = '만들다'
```

But when I try it with:

```
print([*example[-2]])
```

I get

```
['들']
```

While I'm trying to get as output something like:

```
['ㄷ', 'ㅡ', 'ㄹ']
```

Comment: I can't provide an actual answer since I don't know about this specific thing but after searching about getting syllables from korean characters I found this https://github.com/JDongian/python-jamo, also `print([*example[-2]])`, you don't seem to know what it does, this only prints out the second last item in a list representation of each char in the string passed, it won't do any processing to it.

Comment: you mean like `print(list(example))`?

Comment: It’s a single character, which you can’t simply destructure with list operations. You need to work with Unicode properties and/or use appropriate libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jamo module to do it

```
from jamo import h2j, j2hcj
example = '만들다'
char = example[-2]
print([*j2hcj(h2j(char))])
```

the jamo library provides a easy interface to Hangul decomposition.
You can also read the [documentation](https://python-jamo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use `unicodedata.normalize()` to decompose each syllable to its constituent parts. Unicode Normalization Form D will decompose a Hangul syllable into its constituent letters.

```py
import unicodedata as ud
example = '만들다'
hangul = example[-2]
print(f"{hangul}: U+{ord(hangul):04X}")
# 들: U+B4E4
jamo = ud.normalize("NFD", example[-2])
cp = ' '.join(f"U+{ord(j):04X}" for j in jamo)
print(f"{jamo}: {cp}")
# 들: U+1103 U+1173 U+11AF
print(list(jamo))
['ᄃ', 'ᅳ', 'ᆯ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the '들' you get from `[*example[-2]]` and decompose it into its components – see my Python code in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579977/finding-index-of-korean-alphabet-any-unicode-char-in-korean-word-any-unicode/12765973#12765973). Call `HangulName()` and you'll get the letters.